# How to concatenate .mat files vertically of same variables with different dimension?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, concatenation

I am having problem with concatenating .mat files. My files are named:

- `ncom_2014_stemp.mat`
- `ncom_2014_stemp.mat`
- ......(total 7 of them)

and the variables are like this:

- `lat` = 664x1 double
- `lon` = 544x1 double
- `sst` = 664x544x2920 double
- `t` = 2920x1 double

For the 7 different files, the `sst` and `t` change. Otherwise the `lat` and `lon` are the same for all. I want to add all the variables to one .mat file vertically. Tried lots of solution from QA but nothing comes up.

Comment: Seems like it might be better to just load all the `.mat` files into MATLAB/the MATLAB workspace and save all variables to one mat file. I'm not sure, the exact way you would like to concatenate them due to the varying dimensions. Another option to entertain could be saving them into a struct and then to a `.mat` file.

Comment: I wanted to concatenate the variables vertically, one after another, so that I can use them all. That was the main point

Comment: Oh, my bad you want to concatenate the `sst` and `t` variables respectively. That can be done by simply loaded the `.mat` files and using the `vertcat()` function or `[ ; ]`.